# How do I redirect to an ftp:// url with Spring Webflow?

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-webflow

I'm trying to use Spring WebFlow to redirect to a computed url to an ftp server, but in the ExternalRedirect code are the following lines:

```
} else if (location.startsWith("http://") || location.startsWith("https://")) {
    sendRedirect(location, request, response);
} else {
    sendServletRelativeRedirect(location, request, response);
}
```

Is there any way to get Spring WebFlow to redirect to, say, ftp://example.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using this:
http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

I have it setup with every spring project I work on.

Comment: I've changed jobs since then, and now don't have to work with Spring WebFlow anymore, so I haven't tested out your answer, but I'm going to accept it, since really, no-one else has said anything in 2.5 years.  :)  Thanks!